# Is there a way to add Skyrim-like quest markers in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Going back for a yet another playthrough of Fallout New Vegas, is there a way to add quest markers on doors and above people similar to Skyrim?

Comment: If you're playing on PC I would recommend checking out the [Steam Workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/app/22380/discussions/0/846955554776611438) or [Fallout New Vegas' Nexus Mods site](http://steamcommunity.com/app/22380/discussions/0/846955554776611438) for a mod that might add your desired feature.

Comment: @BlueBarren Thanks, couldn't find anything. Perhaps something exists, so I'm hoping to find it with help here.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just set a marker on the map, but I don't see a source confirming that, so I'd have to check it on my game. You can check it once you start playing and get back to us. Just click somewhere on the pip-boy map. It would mark doors if you need to go through the door to get to the marker, but I don't think you can mark people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can research it's possible, but I haven't tried it myself.

According to [this conversation](https://steamcommunity.com/app/22380/discussions/0/1470841715969682790/) on Steam forums a Mod called The Solid Project adds floating quest markers to the game. The mod also adds some other features like sprinting mechanics, door opening and item-grabbing animations and combat takedowns to the game, so you'll have to tolerate those if you want the quest markers.

For whatever reason the mod [has been set to hidden](https://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/63239) on the Nexus website so it cannot be downloaded there. You can, however use [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwsvk63bftllhby/Solid%20Project%20V18-63239-18-1549630285.rar?dl=0) I had [found on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/avqkbh/fnv_solid_project_has_been_taken_down_heres_a_link/) to download the mod from Dropbox instead.

Here's a video which shows off the features of The Solid Project. Waypoints/floating markers are presented at 6:03.